# JSONException: No value for

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

Getting the following error in my code, I believe it is not reading my JSON correctly and I don't understand why, it was working fine before I made a few changes last week but I forgot what changes I made.

> W/System.err(1551): org.json.JSONException: No value for uid

Basically, this program is to login with a username/pass and pass the data from a MySQL database using JSON parsing into the next activity. On pressing the login button, It sends an HTTP request to a PHP page which validates in MySQL and returns a JSON string (array) of the users data to the next activity.

This activity shows up, but it's blank, and it should be displaying all the persons info in different TextViews but it's not.

Here is a JSON output example:

> {"users":[{"fullname":"Adam","displayname":"adamator","email":"123","password":"123","created_at":"2013-11-30 11:20:31","updated_at":"2013-11-30 11:34:08"}]}

So what I would like to do is to display what is in the JSON object in the logcat or in a pop up message or something so that I can see if my JSON parser is working properly. How can I do this? Or if someone can see a problem in my code that I am missing, that would be even better.

Here is my Homepage.java

```
public class Homepage extends Activity {

    // URL to get JSON Arrays
    public static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/SQL.php?username='";
    public static String usernamefromlogin;
    public static TextView errorchecking;

    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "users";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "fullname";
    private static final String TAG_DISPLAY = "displayname";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_PW = "password";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED = "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_UPDATED = "updated_at";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);

        // Get login name from EditText in login screen and concatenate it to
        // PHP user-name for _GET command in 3 steps.
        // Step 1: Get intent from previous activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        getIntent().getExtras();

        // Step 2: convert intent (intent) to string called "usernamefromlogin"
        // //error checking in log cat to see value of "usernamefromlogin"
        usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2");
        Log.d("log of usernamefromlogin", usernamefromlogin);

        // Step 3: take the string "url" and add string "usernamefromlogin"
        // after it
        String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
        String url6 = url5.concat("'");
        // find TextView "errorchecking" and send the string "url6" to it so it
        // can display in log cat
        Log.d("log of URL6 in it's final state", url6);

        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL from the final string "url6"
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url6);
        // Logcat check value for TAG_USER

        try {
            // Getting JSON Array

            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing JSON item in a String Variable
            String uid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            String created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            String updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);

            // Importing TextView
            final TextView uid1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvuid);
            final TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
            final TextView display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayname);
            final TextView email1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvemail);
            final TextView pw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvpassword);
            final TextView created1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
            final TextView updated1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);

            ImageView imgView;
            imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

            // Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView
            uid1.setText(uid);
            name1.setText(name);
            display1.setText(display);
            email1.setText(email);
            pw1.setText(pw);
            created1.setText(created);
            updated1.setText(updated);

            // print error if applicable.
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.sencide;

import learn2crack.jsonparsing.library.JSONParser;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Homepage extends Activity {

    // URL to get JSON Arrays
    public static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android/SQL.php?username='";
    public static String usernamefromlogin;
    public static TextView errorchecking;

    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "users";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "fullname";
    private static final String TAG_DISPLAY = "displayname";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_PW = "password";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED = "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_UPDATED = "updated_at";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);

        // Get login name from EditText in login screen and concatenate it to
        // PHP user-name for _GET command in 3 steps.
        // Step 1: Get intent from previous activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        getIntent().getExtras();

        // Step 2: convert intent (intent) to string called "usernamefromlogin"
        // //error checking in log cat to see value of "usernamefromlogin"
        usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2");
        Log.d("log of usernamefromlogin", usernamefromlogin);

        // Step 3: take the string "url" and add string "usernamefromlogin"
        // after it
        String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
        String url6 = url5.concat("'");
        // find TextView "errorchecking" and send the string "url6" to it so it
        // can display in log cat
        Log.d("log of URL6 in it's final state", url6);

        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL from the final string "url6"
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url6);
        // Logcat check value for TAG_USER

        try {
            // Getting JSON Array

            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing JSON item in a String Variable
            String uid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
            String created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
            String updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);

            // Importing TextView
            final TextView uid1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvuid);
            final TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
            final TextView display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayname);
            final TextView email1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvemail);
            final TextView pw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvpassword);
            final TextView created1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
            final TextView updated1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);

            ImageView imgView;
            imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

            // Set JSON Data in its respectable TextView
            uid1.setText(uid);
            name1.setText(name);
            display1.setText(display);
            email1.setText(email);
            pw1.setText(pw);
            created1.setText(created);
            updated1.setText(updated);

            // print error if applicable.
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Get one hand off that woman on you profile's picture and use it to deploy a versioning repository?

Comment: Your JSOn obviously doesn't have a `uid` element.

Comment: your json does not have uid, what would you expect ?

Comment: btw, you posted twice the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

There is no `uid` in your JSONObject in your response you have to check with `c.has(TAG_ID)` that TAG name present or not.

```
        String uid = "";
        String name = "";
        String display = "";
        String email = "";
        String pw = "";
        String created = "";
        String updated = "";

        if(c.has(TAG_ID))
           uid = c.getString(TAG_ID);

        if(c.has(TAG_NAME))
           name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

        if(c.has(TAG_DISPLAY))
           display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);

        if(c.has(TAG_EMAIL))
           email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

        if(c.has(TAG_PW))
           pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);

        if(c.has(TAG_CREATED))
           created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);

        if(c.has(TAG_UPDATED))
           updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);
```

Comment: I am an idiot, thank you, I removed all references to UID and this resolved my problem.

It's strange though that one of my strings missing data didn't crash my app.  Even stranger is the activity processed and the other strings that did have data didn't show up... 

Anyway, thank you again.